# How to create nested ember route when each parent has same child ids?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I am using ember-cli from a rails api to try and display the lecture template of a nested route. This is my router:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('home');
  this.resource('courses', function() {
      this.resource('course', { path: '/:course_id' }, function() {
        this.resource('lecture', { path: '/lecture/:lecture_id' });
      });
    });
});
```

I have no trouble displaying individual lectures in a course template using:

```
{{#each lecture in lectures}}
  {{#link-to 'lecture' lecture classNames='list-group-item'}}{{lecture.name}}{{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
```

So I can see in the ember inspector that my courses and lecture data loads with no troubles. The problem is that when I click on that link, it displays the right URL up top but the page doesn't change.

**Course Model:**

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    lectures: DS.hasMany('lecture',  {async: true})
});
```

**Lecture Model:**

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    level: DS.attr('string'),
    course: DS.belongsTo('course')
});
```

My ideal scenario would be for the route to point to the level parameter since each course can have lecture levels 1-8, but I am not sure how to even get it to display the ember id because this route does **not** work:

**Lecture Route:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('lecture', params.lecture_id);
    }
});
```

Can anyone give me guidance on how to make this nested ember route possible?  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have an outlet defined in your template for your 'course' route.  Without an outlet and content in your 'lecture' template, nothing is going to show up.

Comment: Thank you so much, that totally was it! I guess I was confused because I apparently did not need a {{outlet}} in the courses template to view the course template, but I did need one on the course template to see the lecture template.